# How to add beta parameter to F1 Score for fit_resample in TidyModel

Tags: tidymodels, yardstick

I am using the fit_resamples() function in TidyModels to get the F1 metrics as below.
I would like to know how to pass the **beta** parameter whose default is set at **1** at the moment.

```
glm_workflow %>%
  fit_resamples(resamples = trainDatFolds,
                metrics = metric_set(roc_auc, pr_auc,
                                     accuracy, f_meas),
                control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE) %>%
  collect_metrics()
```

Thanks a lot!

Zarni

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a simple wrapper for the metric. See [`?metric_set`](https://yardstick.tidymodels.org/reference/metric_set.html). The examples include one where the `ccc()` function is used with an argument.